# UIButton is resized to fit UIImage

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, resize, constraints

```
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
    btn.setImage(..., for: UIControlState.normal)
    addSubview(btn)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.superview!.rightAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
    btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 6 + vc.view.safeAreaInsets.top).isActive = true
    btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
    btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)

    btn.backgroundColor = .black //to check the rect
```

The size of the image is 16x16. The button should be larger at least twice (because of small touch area).

But when I run the app the button becomes 16x22 (22 - height). In "debug view hierarchy" I also see that its constraints become `width==16` and `height==22`.
In the same time distance constraints work normally.

So what is my mistake? Or must I use image resources which fit buttons 1:1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It tells the button that it shouldn't hug its contents, and spread out according to its other constraints:

```
btn.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
btn.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
```

Comment: No, the result is the same